# Kotlin Non-nullable Generics

Tags: android, kotlin, null

I have encountered a peculiarity when adding null to a collection of non-nullable type.

It is best illustrated by the following code examples:

```
val a = LongSparseArray<String>()
a.put(1L, null)
a.toArrayList().filterNotNull()
// bad - no error, but warns that "filterNotNull" is a "Useless call on collection type", when it clearly isn't

val b = LongSparseArray<String?>()
b.put(1L, null)
b.toArrayList().filterNotNull()
// good

val c = HashMap<Long, String>()
c.put(1L, null)
// compilation error - good

val d = HashMap<Long, String?>()
d.put(1L, null)
// good
```

When using some collections (SparseArray, LongSparseArray) of String, I am freely able to add null, and Kotlin's null-safety does not pick up on it. When using others (HashMap), Kotlin's null safety prevents it, unless I use the String? type.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that the values of LongSparseArray are not null?

Comment: What Kotlin version?

Comment: `LongSparseArray` is a Java class, so Kotlin allows using both nullable and non-null values with it. `HashMap` is a Kotlin class, so it has full nullability checks.

Comment: I'm using Kotlin 1.2.50

Comment: @yole Thanks, that makes sense. Is there any way I can ensure the values of LongSparseArray are not null though?

Comment: You can change the declaration of LongSparseArray and add nullability annotations, or convert it to Kotlin.

Comment: wonderful, thank you! :)